# Facebook group chat - fetch complete chat content without paging

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net, facebook

**What I want**

> I want to be able to copy/paste the entire content of a chat to memory
>   so I can extract included YouTube urls from it.

**What I know**

As you may know, the group chat(s) run on a separate url and are loaded page by page. Normally you go to the previous page either by simply scrolling upwards, or by clicking on a *show previous* link (works differently on different devices I think).

**Things I tried**

Sadly I can't find the urls to either anymore, but ...

***Add a script to Chrome console***

The point was to add a script that went looking for the *show previous* link and clicked it.

***Add a start=0 parameter to the url***

This assumes you can find out the actual url, either manually or through something like Fiddler.

The idea was that you add something like *?start=0* to the url. This would cause the paging to start from the very first record and load all.

> *Both solutions didn't work.*

Possibly this is because Facebook made these options obsolete. It's my impression that Facebook initially provided more dev options than it does now.

**My question**

> What can I do to fully load chat content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now this is the nearest thing I can find:

https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10200611181580779

> There is a way to see your complete chat history on Facebook easily.
>   By this method you can also see Photos or videos you've shared on
>   Facebook. Your Wall posts etc. -- 'A copy of what you've shared on
>   Facebook' Follow these steps:
>
> 1. Go to 'Account Settings'
> 2. Click on 'Download a copy of your Facebook data' from bottom of General section
> 3. Then click 'Start My Archive' -- It may take a little while for gather your photos, wall posts, messages, and other information.
>      (Usually 20 to 60 minutes)
> 4. Once Archive generated Download it.
> 5. Extract and open 'index.html' from downloaded folder
> 6. Now you can see 'Messages' on bottom of the page, click it.
>
> Done!

I got a response in my mail way faster than 20 minutes.

You will get a mail with a link to a zip file, containing your archive:

> ***In the html folder you find:*** messages.htm

For that I can write a script that looks for YouTube URLs in that file.

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure what this has to do with C#, but i'll give a C# solution anyways. My solution would be to use something such as HTMLAgilityPack to get the InnerHTML from a page once it's loaded, although this will obviously require some type of authentication, so for this I suggest using something like a WebClient and sending along Auth credentials with whatever it is you're doing, OR just create a method to login, then use the same webclient to access chats via URL, use DownloadString() to get the contents of the page then using HTMLAgilityPack's methods to get the InnerHTML of whatever the chat box is called/indentified as.

Comment: Your response is exactly why C# is flagged. It can/could be the solution. I'll look into your suggestion.